# Can the preferred replica and the leader be different Brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka

When we run a topic describe, we can see in the fourth column the list of replicas in order of the preferred replicas, always I see that the first replica on the list is the same as leader. I wonder if Can the preferred replica and the leader be different Brokers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be different

> In an ideal scenario, the leader for a given partition should be the "preferred replica". This guarantees that the leadership load across the brokers in a cluster are evenly balanced. However, over time the leadership load could get imbalanced due to broker shutdowns (caused by controlled shutdown, crashes, machine failures etc).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-1.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionTool